# Different behavior running script from cli or Nautilus?

Tags: scripts

I have made two scripts in ~/bin, test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/<username>/bin/test2.sh & disown
```

and test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/notify-send "test!"
```

and when I `./test.sh` it works as expected but when I launch it from Nautilus, there is no notification, I'm seeing the terminal window blink in and out of existence, and nothing. I tried adding `read line` and `$shell`to test2.sh but to no effect.

What would be the cause for the difference, and how to make it work from nautilus as it does from command line?

update: if `& disown` is omitted from first script, second script runs as expected.

Comment: Does notification appear if you call `/usr/bin/notify-send` from the first script , `test.sh` ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yes, it does! But not from the second, unless ran from cli.

Comment: So the issue is likely with the script not inheriting environment form the second script.   At least that's what I suspect.

Comment: I've tested with my own two scripts, they work alright, notification shows up properly.

Comment: Did you use & disown? I just tried omitting it, and then it worked from Nautilus.

Comment: yes, i omitted `& disown` part as well.

Comment: But it still works if i add the `& disown` to the second script call

Comment: In my example case the '& disown' is in script 1, which runs first. Please try that and run script 1 from nautilus. I tried these exact scripts on 14.04 and 16.04 machines and behavior was identical, no notification when ran from nautilus. If they work for you, I can't fathom what's going on...

Comment: It could be difference in Nautilus version. Im using 16.04. What's your Ubuntu and Nautilus version ?

Comment: nautilus 3.10.1, on both 16.04 and 14.04 machines.